# FFmpeg libavfilter watermark?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Since the vhook subsystem has been removed from the latest version of FFMPEG, how can I add a watermark to a video?

the following software is installed on my server:

FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1 with libavfilter 0.4.0

for example: --> but this code does not work.

```
exec('ffmpeg -i 01.mpg  -vfilters "movie=0:png:watermark.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" -f  flv 03.flv');
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think -vfilters is recognized: use -vf instead. movie doesn't take a list of undefined  colon delimited arguments (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-movie)

Try :

```
ffmpeg -i 01.mpg -vf "movie=watermark.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" -f flv 03.flv
```