# How to put watermark on video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

So I installed ffmpeg etc and it seems to work ok but for some reason I don't have watermark.so on my server. I have a watermark.c in a folder called gpac_extra_libs. Maybe I missed something in the install, does anybody know what I need to do to get watermark.so on a Centos 5.x 64bit?

Comment: By installing do you mean you compiled it from source? Also, which revision did you use?

Comment: yes from source, its the latest version from git

Comment: Ok, if it's the latest version, then it uses libavfilter to put watermarks, older versions used vhook, but that's deprecated now. See if you have libavfilter enabled in your build, and for how to use it, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5542534/492336).

Comment: Ah ok I see it is installed, something must have changed since the last version because now I seem to have to use the [scale] tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934420/ffmpeg-how-to-scale-a-video-then-apply-a-watermark and changed [watermark] to [logo] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542534/ffmpeg-libavfilter-watermark and now it works again. Thanks for your help satuon